# Setup DNS server on a Leopard machine?

Tags: macos, dns, osx-leopard, nameserver

What is the easiest way to setup a DNS server on a Leopard machine?  Does Leopard come with a DNS server? My Leopard machine's virtual name is  **abc.local**.  I want to add this to the DNS server.

Comment: note that the **.local** is provided by Apple's **mDNS/Zeroconf** implementation called [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking#Apple_Bonjour).  other machines on your network that run Bonjour or Avahi can resolve **abc.local** directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leopard comes with the famous [**BIND**](http://www.isc.org/software/bind) package. It is actually the most popular DNS implementation on the internet. You can [**configure the files yourself**](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/mac/2003/04/15/bind.html) or optionally use the GUI tool, DNS Enabler, as pointed out by lajuette.

Answer (score 1):

I think this tool will help you with that:
http://cutedgesystems.com/software/DNSEnablerForLeopard/

Leopard comes with a DNS Server.